# how to encrypt a file before uploading in django

Tags: python, django, cryptography, aes

Im building a project secure file sharing.which encrypts a file before uploading into local computer and decrypts while downloading if the user has the decryption key.I was stuck how to encrypt a file before uploading into my pc

I'm following this approach which is mentioned below.

https://ruddra.com/documentation-of-django-encrypt-file/#basic-usage

but i dont't know how to link with my code. can anyone help me

views.py

```
def upload(request):
    context={}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        upload_file= request.FILES["document"]
        fs=FileSystemStorage()
        name=fs.save(upload_file.name, upload_file)
        context['url'] = fs.url(name)
    return render(request, 'accounts/upload.html',context)
```

upload.html

```
{% include 'accounts/main.html'%}

<pre>
Upload your files for sharing
</pre>


{% block content %}

  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="document">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>
  {% if url %}

  <p> Uploaded file:<a href="{{ url }}">{{ url }}</a></p>
  {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL= '/media/'
```

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/eblocha/django-encrypted-files, or you can install the library using 'pip install django-encrypted-files'

Answer (score 1):

To encrypt a file BEFORE uploading to the server, it means you need to encrypt it within the browser - e.g. using JavaScript. Here's a thread that can help you to encrypt stuff in JS:
[JavaScript AES encryption and decryption (Advanced Encryption Standard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51531021/javascript-aes-encryption-and-decryption-advanced-encryption-standard)

If you're feeling up to the challenge, look into running AES in WASM to speed up encryption (important for large files).

Note that in Django, all python code is executed ON THE SERVER. The linked example in the question shows how to encrypt files on the server AFTER uploading them:
https://ruddra.com/documentation-of-django-encrypt-file/#basic-usage

Note that encrypting the file on the browser before uploading is only a small portion of the whole problem. To have a secure file sharing service, you would probably want to have a way to share the key with the other users who need to decrypt it. For that you'd probably need to use asymmetric encryption, e.g., wrap (encrypt) the key using other users' public keys before uploading it.

Comment: I'm not really in the security field, but I'd say overriding django's [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) method to add specific tasks when saving the model would be ok ? (True enough it would still be up to you to make sure any temp file is properly removed, specially in case of failure). Do you think this would cause any issue ?

Comment: @tgrandje django's save method is executed server side - after transferring file to the server. The author, however, wants to "encrypts a file before uploading" - thus it needs to be done in the browser (e.g. with Javascript).

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question indeed... But I'm not sure there would be a big issue with executing the encryption on the server side (I was in fact reacting to your last paragraph, about encrypting the file on the browser beeing a first step) : if the save method doesn't store the encryption key an makes sure to purge any temp file, I'd say it would be good enough for most purposes ?

Comment: Then what is the purpose? :) In most cases, no encryption is needed, just proper access control (which includes full disk encryption) would be sufficient. Generally, security is risk management with multiple layers of protection. You might be interested in reading how AWS controls access to user data:
https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/data-center/controls/

If access control is done right, having server-side encryption only addressed limited scenarios (e.g. adversary cannot access data uploaded before server was taken over). I mean you can do it but I don't think it would add much to users.